# Remove encoding for popovers on labels

Tags: yii2, popover

I'm using Yii2 to generate a popover on a label, but having some trouble to remove the default HTML encoding. I'm not sure that the popover can be created for just the label without HTML encoding and what the correct way to do this is, it must be possible though as Gii uses some variant of this code? This is what I've tried:

```
  <?= $form->field($model, 'function')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])
                                  ->label(null, [
                                    'class' => 'dashed-line',
                                    'data-toggle' => 'popover',
                                    'data-content' => 'This will be ran through <code>strtolower()</code>',
                                    'data-placement' => 'right',
                                    'encodeLabel'=> false]) ?>
```

[image]

Comment: No, I want the `<code>` tags to be rendered as HTML

Comment: Hmm did some research. I do not think it is possible and I also think that is by design as this could break things. What if you entered `"<style` as the data-content? If it is not encoded, then the whole label + html will break.

Comment: It must be because it is in Gii

Comment: Ok got it. Gii is not doing anything fancy. gii has a model called Generator, which extends absract class `\yii\gii\Generator`. This has a method called `hints()`. So, you will need to look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
['labelOptions' => ['encode' => false]]
```

.

```
<?= $form->field($model, ['labelOptions' => ['encode' => false]] ,
       'function')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])
                              ->label(null, [
                                'class' => 'dashed-line',
                                'data-toggle' => 'popover',
                                'data-content' => 'This will be ran through <code>strtolower()</code>',
                                'data-placement' => 'right',
                                ) ?>
```

you can use  label option for setting the encode false of label attribute

```
   <?= $form->field($model, 
       'function')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])
                              ->label(null, [
                                'class' => 'dashed-line',
                                'data-toggle' => 'popover',
                                'data-content' => 'This will be ran through <code>strtolower()</code>',
                                'data-placement' => 'right',
                                'encode' => false,
                                ) ?>
```

Comment: inside lable()? Because I tried that and the tags are still encoded :-(

Comment: This gives me `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` in  in C:\xampp\htdocs\ccasper-reporting\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\helpers\BaseArrayHelper.php

Comment: this will make the label support html, not it's attributes..in this case `data-content` ;)

Comment: You can sue label options  ..i have update the answer